# How to integrate third-part iOS sdk to react native

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

It seems the react native have the ability to integrate iOS project and using it as the normal react component, but I have read the official document and find there is no complete demo, is there a simple way to show how to do it begin to the end?

Comment: Please read the [help] before posting.

Comment: Thanks for remind, but I will still wait for a answer.

Comment: Well if you read the [help] you might realize that your question doesn’t follow the Stack Overflow guidelines, therefor it’s very unlikely you’ll get an answer, and even if you do, the chances of it being a quality answer are very slim. If you don’t take the time to write a good question and follow the guidelines why should we take the time to write a good answer?

Comment: You're right, I will try to follow this rule and also try to improve my question quality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is React Native Modules

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios

In the documentation they have the following example which you can follow along with and implement, then modify to fit your needs.

#### CalendarManager.h

> ```
> // CalendarManager.h
> #import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
>
> @interface CalendarManager : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule>
> @end
> ```

#### CalendarManager.m

> ```
> // CalendarManager.m
> #import "CalendarManager.h"
> #import <React/RCTLog.h>
>
> @implementation CalendarManager
>
> RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();
>
> RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(addEvent:(NSString *)name location:(NSString *)location)
> {
>   RCTLogInfo(@"Pretending to create an event %@ at %@", name, location);
> }
> ```

This example doesn't really do anything, it just created a method called `CalendarManager.addEvent` that you can call from React Native that will console log some stuff using `RCTLog`.

#### Breakdown

- `.h file` - The header file that connects iOS to React Native, pretty much nothing goes in here except what's shown (changed to match your module name)
- `.m file` - The module file that defines your methods that you call in JavaScript in which can call your SDK methods.
- `@implementation CalendarManager` - This is where you name your module, so you an import it in ReactNative with `NativeModules.CalendarManager`
- `RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()` - Defines that this file is a React Native module
- `RCT_EXPORT_METHOD()` - Defines a method you can call from React Native. You can have as many of these as you want.

Inside your `RCT_EXPORT_METHOD()` definition, you can call your SDK with whatever parameters you pass it.

Talking of parameters, there are different types that are defined as follows:

> - string (NSString)
> - number (NSInteger, float, double, CGFloat, NSNumber)
> - boolean (BOOL, NSNumber)
> - array (NSArray) of any types from this list
> - object (NSDictionary) with string keys and values of any type from this list
> - function (RCTResponseSenderBlock)